# Show something before setInterval jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

my question is how can i show instant some information before load setInterval in jquery, and when is load setInterval will update it.

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function getData(){
        $(\"#whereshow\").load(\"somefile.php\");
    }
    setInterval(\"getData()\", 5000);
</script>
```

Can i make something like that?

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    function getData1(){
        $(\"#whereshow\").load(\"somefile.php\");
    }
    function getData(){
        $(\"#whereshow\").load(\"somefile.php\");
    }
    setInterval(\"getData()\", 5000);
</script>
```

...and getData1() will display instant onload page info, then will stop, and setIntervall wil do the other update job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is have the `setInterval` fire immediately as well as on the interval.

That's easy.

```
(function() {
    var getData = function() {
        $("#whereshow").load("somefile.php");
    }
    setInterval(getData,5000);
    getData();
})();
```

See, just call the function ;) I also added some improvements to your script.

---

EDIT: Another way of doing it that I just thought of:

```
setInterval((function() {
    $("#whereshow").load("somefile.php");
    return arguments.callee;
})(),5000);
```

Comment: The second solution was really clever. Not readable, but still very neat.